# What would be the date time string

Tags: c#

what should be the date string format for mm/dd/yyyy
where iam using below code.

```
txtActDate.Text = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

but getting output in this format 5-27-2015

Comment: Soo... what did you expect?

Comment: Are you sure it is `5-27-2015` and not `05-27-2015` ? What do you expect anyway?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: iam expecting like 5/27/2015

Answer (score 3):

If I look at the result, the numbers `5`, `27` and `2015` are in perfect order. I guess you are wondering about the dashes, and why there are no slashes.

In a format-string, the slashes are seen as seperators which will be replaced by the seperator of the current culture. You have two options:

- Use another culture which is conform your whishes (for example: `en-US`)
- Reformat your format-string: `MM\/dd\/yyyy`. Using these backslashes, you tell the formatting mechanism that you realy realy want those slahses :)
- Reformat your format-string where the slashes are between quotes: `MM'/'dd'/'yyyy` (as suggested by Tim).

So the following code results in three times the same and desired texts:

```
string result1 = new DateTime(2015, 5, 27).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
string result2 = new DateTime(2015, 5, 27).ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy");
string result3 = new DateTime(2015, 5, 27).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");
```

For more informatie, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Instead of `MM\/dd\/yyyy` you have to use `MM'/'dd'/'yyyy` (or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Have to? Or is it just an alternative?

Comment: You _have_ to use it since your code doesn't compile, try `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")`. You can use `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");` or `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: It DOES compile, as long as you comply to the c#-string rules. So you could use: `.ToString("MM\\/dd\\/yyyy")` or `.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the Thread CurrentCulture you have in your application , if you need it in specific format, set the Thread CurrentCulture property, pass CultureInfo to specific culture you want in ToString method or just format it yourself like:

txtActDate.Text = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", dateTime.Day.ToString(), dateTime.Month.ToString(), dateTime.Year.ToString());

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
txtActDate.Text = txtActDate.Text.Replace('-', '/');
```

Comment: This is not a solution, it is a fix. A fix needed for people who do not understand the formatting-mechanism. Please use the correct mechanisms.